# Magento2 get Shipping Rates Programmatically

Tags: magento2, shipping

Let me know how to get Shipping rates Programmatically, I tried with default `collectrates()`, Still it's not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will help you

```
     $quote = $this->checkoutSession->getQuote();
     $address = $quote->getShippingAddress();
     $address->collectShippingRates();
```

Comment: If i have to print the rates, Do i have to call any function?

Comment: you have to pass quote id.

Comment: foreach ($address->getAllShippingRates() as $rate)
        {
            $shippingAmount += $rate->getPrice();
        }, It worked after this piece of code.

Comment: There is some way to get the quotation without a checkout session object? I'm trying to get it on product page ...

Comment: @Vishnunath, can we apply particular table_rate for the address?

Comment: @Vishnunath, how to get the rate value here?

Answer (score 0):

Please find the sample code below for getting shipping rates. you have to pass quoteId

```
    use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;

    require dirname(__FILE__) . '/../app/bootstrap.php';

    $bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);

    $obj = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();

    $state = $obj->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
    $state->setAreaCode('frontend');

    $quote = $obj->get('Magento\Checkout\Model\Session')->getQuote()->load(1);
    $address = $quote->getShippingAddress();
    $address->collectShippingRates();
    print_r($address->getData());
    //print_r($quote->getOrigData());
```